# need to render python in html using flask

Tags: python, flask

this is the 1st time I am rendering HTML using python and flask so my concepts are very new..

I tried the `A Simple Example` in [Project](https://pypi.org/project/Flask/) and my issue is if I change **return "Hello, World!"** in the hello() python function to say **return "ABC XYZ"** and do a **refresh** of the browser url(http://127.0.0.1:5000/), the new value (ABC XYZ) doesnt get rendered immediately; so how do I make it to render upon a browser refresh?

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the Flask application does not auto-reload even if you make any changes in code files.

But if you want Flask to auto-reload whenever you save(or change) any file then you have to set debug to `True`

If you are using `app.run()` then do this

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

or if you running it using a command line like `flask run`. Then add `--debug` in the command.

###### example

> flask --app FileName run --debug

Comment: worked ` flask --app Project(here instead of Project I put the python file name) run --debug `